# Python child class decorator. Why can I qualify decorators with parent class only once

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

I tried this code in python 3.6

```python
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class A(ABC):

  @property
  @abstractmethod
  def prop1(self):
    pass
    
  @prop1.setter
  @abstractmethod
  def prop1(self, val):
    pass

class B(A):
  def __init__(self, val=None):
    self._prop = val

  @A.prop1.setter
  def prop1(self, val):
    if val == "something":
      self._prop = val
    else:
      self._prop = "nothing"

  @A.prop1.getter
  def prop1(self):
    return self._prop

  def do_something(self):
    self.prop1 = "blah"
```

I get the error `TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class B with abstract methods prop1`. But if I remove `@A` from the overridden getter like so, the code works fine.

```python
@prop1.getter
 def prop1(self):
   return self._prop
```

Furthermore, it doesn't matter if the getter is above or below the setter. Only the very first one seems to need the `@A.`. Why is that so?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to reference the base classes properties at all when overriding them in the subclass

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class A(ABC):

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def prop1(self):
        pass

    @prop1.setter
    @abstractmethod
    def prop1(self, val):
        pass


class B(A):
    def __init__(self, val=None):
        self._prop = val

    @property
    def prop1(self):
        return self._prop

    @prop1.setter
    def prop1(self, val):
        if val == "something":
            self._prop = val
        else:
            self._prop = "nothing"

    def do_something(self):
        self.prop1 = "blah"
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. But if I place the getter function decorated with `@property` after the setter function, I get the error `@prop1 is not defined`. Seems like there's some kind of scoping/order rules involved.

Comment: You can't use a variable/function before it's defined...